# Delete button only deleted first row in gridview

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, gridview, ado.net

I added a delete button in my GridView. But the problem is it always deletes the first row.

For instance, if I am deleting the the second or the third row, the data in the first row will be deleted. I just want the button to delete the row beside it:

```
public void bindgrid()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("cnString");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Id,Name, from myTable ", conn);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("", conn);
    da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select Id,Name, from myTable", conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "data");
    gridview1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    gridview1.DataBind();
}


protected void gdview_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    int userid = int.Parse(gridview1.DataKeys[0].Value.ToString());
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("cnString");
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("", conn);
    conn.Open();
    da.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand("delete from myTable where Id=" + userid , conn);

    da.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    bindgrid();
}
```

Comment: you need to get the row indes where you clicked

Comment: You should look for selected row of gridview, then take ID of that row and then go for delete part.It seems to me that you are always grabbing ID of first row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the current row index instead of `gridview1.DataKeys[0]`

```
 protected void gdview_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
   {
    int userid = int.Parse(gridview1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("cnString");
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("", conn);
    conn.Open();
    da.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand("delete from myTable where Id=" + userid , conn);

    da.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    bindgrid();
   }
```

Comment: I get this error when I use e.rowIndex:   (CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'rowIndex' and no extension method 'rowIndex' accepting a first argument of type)

Comment: it worked now  thanks I just used e.RowIndex  instead of e.rowIndex  to avoid the error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in below line

```
int userid = int.Parse(gridview1.DataKeys[0].Value.ToString());
```

You are always getting the userid of the first row by using [0]

Get the appropriate value from "e" and pass that.

```
e.RowIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

something llike this

```
GridViewRow row = gridview1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
int userid = int.Parse(row[0].Value.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
int userid = int.Parse(gridview1.DataKeys[0].Value.ToString());
```

to this

```
int userid = int.Parse(gridview1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: I get this error: (The best overloaded method match for 'int.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments)